# How to display list of problems in Scala code using IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-13

The problems scope in IntelliJ in a Scala project always seems to be empty even if the compiler has listed errors.  Is there some other way to view a consolidated list of problems?

[image]

Comment: Be aware that IDEA's Scala support is not based on the Scala compiler (or its so-called “presentation compiler”) and frequently disagrees with the Scala compiler. It is not a reliable indicator of either errors or their absence.

Comment: `sbt compile` (in sbt console) :)